# Worst case scenarios for companion matrix method

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, roots, rounding-error, companion-matrices

In what case is the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) method for computing the roots of a polynomial expected to suffer accuracy loss.  Are nearby roots the main issue?

Comment: Google search with keywords "condition number" and "companion matrix" will give you a good harvest...

Comment: Ah, condition number is a useful search term.  Thanks.